# Callback class in Retrofit does not work when its parameter set as generic

Tags: java, android, generics, gson, retrofit

Json:

```
[
{
    "name": "john",
    "surname": "butler",
    "age": 18
},
{
    "name": "bryan",
    "surname": "butler",
    "age": 22
},
{
    "name": "adam",
    "surname": "butler",
    "age": 28
}
]
```

And the Interface:

```
public interface ListAPI<T> {

@GET(EndPoint.LIST_URL)
void getPersonelList(@Path("name") String name,
           Callback<List<Personel>> response);
}
```

if the type is defining explicitly like above everything is working correctly (Callback< List < Personel > > ) but it's defining in previous class like below then json data is converting as LinkedTreeMap by Retrofit which is not expected.

```
public class PersonelListActivity extends ListeActivity<List<Personel>>{
```

............

```
public abstract class ListeActivity<T> extends BaseActivity {

protected ListManager<T> listManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listManager = new ListManager<>(this);
```

....

```
public class ListManager<T> extends BaseManager<ListAPI<T>> {

public ListManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public void getAritmaList (String name, ResponseListener<T> responseListener){
    getBaseActivity().showProgress();
    getApi(ListAPI.class).getAritmaList(name, new Retrofit.RetroCallback<>(responseListener));
}

}

public interface ListAPI<T> {

@GET(EndPoint.LIST_URL)
void getAritmaList(@Path("name") String name,
           Callback<T> response);
}
```

As I said, if I explicitly define the type as List < Personel >  in ListAPI interface everything works. Why it does not work while moving type as generic?

Comment: have you tried instead of `Callback<T> response` to use   `Callback<List<T>> response` ?

Comment: What error it shows?

Comment: there is no error, it just parses json data as linkedtreemap

Comment: I don't see any place where you are actually passing a type parameter down to your `ListAPI<T>`. Could you post the implementation of `getApi`? Also, there is no type argument here: `listManager = new ListManager<>(this);
` - so not even the ListManager knows a type argument, right?

Comment: Look above, ListManager<T> extends BaseManager<ListAPI<T>>  and protected ListManager<T> listManager.

Comment: That's going a bit too deep into Java generics for my expertise, but I'd be surprised if the instance you are creating in `listManager = new ListManager<>(this);` knew anything about the type argument of the instance variable you are declaring in `protected ListManager<T> listManager;` And even if it did there is no type argument in `getApi(ListAPI.class)`... So I also don't see how your `RestAdapter` would know the type argument...

Comment: I guess this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427212/java-util-linkedhashmap-cannot-be-cast-to-datalist/31434735#31434735

Comment: Thanks anshul! quoted from above link which is shared by anshul ==> You cannot use generic interfaces with Retrofit. An exception has been added when you try to do this rather than letting it fail in this manner for the next release.