# Retrofit Generic Callback Issues

Tags: java, android, generics, retrofit

I am using Retrofit in my Android application and have a `Response` class to encapsulate the standard response format that is returned from every endpoint in the API.

```
public class Response<T> {

    public List<ResultFlags> resultFlags;
    public List<T> resultData;
    public List<SystemFlags> systemFlags;

}
```

I am trying to create a generalized way to create a Retrofit `Callback` that can be used for every API call. The problem I am encountering is that some of the endpoints have result data and some do not. For example in my Retrofit service class there is one call, `optimizeContacts` that has result data, and another `sendInvites` that does not.

```
@POST("/OptimizeContacts.php")
 void optimizeContacts(
        @Query("action") String action,
        @Query("campaign") String campaign,
        @Body OptimizeContactsParams params,
        Callback<Response<ArrayList<OptimizedContacts>>[]> callback
);

@POST("/SendInvites.php")
void sendInvites(
        @Query("action") String action,
        @Query("MSISDN") String msisdn,
        @Query(value="accessToken", encodeValue=false) String accessToken,
        @Query("campaign") String campaign,
        @Body ArrayList<ViralContact> contacts,
        Callback<Response[]> callback
);
```

So when I try to create a method to return a `Callback` for an endpoint I cannot find a way to support both `Callback<Response<ArrayList<OptimizedContacts>>[]>` and `Callback<Response[]>` types.

Here is my method currently.

```
protected static <P, R extends OttoBusBase> Callback<Response<P>[]> transactionCallbackWithPayload(final Class responseClass,
                                                                                                   final R event) {
    return new Callback<Response<P>[]>() {

        @Override
        public void success(Response<P>[] responses, retrofit.client.Response response) {
            onSuccessPayload(responseClass, event, responses, response);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            onFailure(responseClass, event, error);
        }
    };

}
```

Is there a way that I can handle both `Response<P>[]` and `Response[]` scenarios simply? Will I need to create two methods for each return type? Or can I do it in a single method?

Comment: I had the same issue and here is what Jake replied
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427212/java-util-linkedhashmap-cannot-be-cast-to-datalist/31434735#31434735

Comment: @david-argyle-thacker did you managed to solve this?